# INCLUDE \part IN DOCUMENT, but not in \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, parts, mwe

I have coded the MWE below, where it gives the desire output, except for table of contents.
As i mentioned, In table of contents, i didn't expect the `part` section to appear in `tableofcontents`

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\part{INTRODUCTION}
\chapter{introdu}
\part{PART 1}
\chapter{intro}
intro intro
\part{PART 2}
\chapter{intro}
intro intro
\part{PART 3}
\chapter{intro}
\part{PART 4}
\chapter{555}
CHAPTER INTRO
\newpage
\part{PART 5}
\chapter{another 1}
\part{PART 6}
\chapter{another 2}
\part{APP}
\part*{PUB}
\part*{BIB}
\end{document}
```

The output of the toc is shown below.

[image: toc output, need to exclude 'part']

In the above figure, i dont want `I ITNRODUCTION, II PART, III PART, ..., VII PART` to appear in toc, but i needed in document, which is shown below.

[image: document inner needed]

Comment: `\makeatletter\renewcommand\l@part[2]{}\makeatother`

Answer (score 4):

One (overpowered) solution is to use the [`etoc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) package, which allows vast customization of the table of contents. In particular, if you `\etocsetlevel{<sectioning level>}{6}` any sectioning level, you can hide it from all table of contents listings.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\etocsetlevel{part}{6}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\part{INTRODUCTION}
\chapter{introdu}
\part{PART 1}
\chapter{intro}
intro intro
\part{PART 2}
\chapter{intro}
intro intro
\part{PART 3}
\chapter{intro}
\part{PART 4}
\chapter{555}
CHAPTER INTRO
\newpage
\part{PART 5}
\chapter{another 1}
\part{PART 6}
\chapter{another 2}
\part{APP}
\part*{PUB}
\part*{BIB}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you dear willie. Though, in the table of contents, the numbering of the chapter is different from the document. is there any other option ?

Comment: @Nandy: I do not understand your comment at all. The chapters all have the correct numbers. (chapter 7 corresponds to "another 2"). Can you clarify what you mean by the table of contents having different numbering from the document?